# SQL Syntax IF/THEN/ELSE

Tags: mysql, if-statement

So I've been dreading asking this question - mostly because I'm terrible at logic in excel, and transferring logic statements to SQL is such a struggle for me, but I'm going to try and make this as clear as possible.

I have two tables. One table is `historic_events` and the other is `future_events`. Based on `future_events`, I have another table `confidence_interval` that calculates a z-score telling me based on how many `future_events` will occur, how many `historic_event` data points I will need to calculate a reliable average. Each record in `historic_events` has a unique key called `event_id`. Each record in `confidence_interval` has a field called `service_id` that is unique. The 'service_id' field also exists in 'historic_events' and they can be joined on that field.

So, with all that being said, based on the count of future events by `service_id`, my `confidence_interval` table calculates the z-score. I then need to select records from the `historic_events` table for each `service_id` that satisfy the following parameters

```
Select * EVENT_ID 
From historic_events
where END_DATE is within two calendar years from todays date
and count of `EVENT_ID` is >= `confidence_interval.Z_SCORE`
```

if those parameters are not met, then I want to widen the date value to being within three years.

if those parameters are still not met, I want to widen the date value to being within four years, and then again to five years. If there still aren't enough datapoints after five years, ohwell, we'll settle for what we have. We do not want to look at datapoints that are older than five years.

I want my end result to be a table that has a list of the `EVENT_ID` and I would re-run the SQL query for each `service_id`.

I hope this makes sense - I can figure out the `SELECT` and `FROM`, but totally getting stuck on the `WHERE`.

Comment: How does `future_events` fit into the query? Is `end_date` in `historic_events` or `future_events`? What are the foreign key relationships? can you make a sqlfiddle showing sample data?

Comment: You can't use `IF` statements in SQL queries, only in procedures. What you have to do is `LEFT JOIN` with tables with each `END_DATE` criteria. Then use a `CASE` expression to get the first one with non-null data.

Comment: Barmar - you are right - future_events is extraneous data - sorry for providing too much! :) 'END_DATE' is in 'historic_events', so what I need to do is pull a list of records by 'OFS_ID' from 'historic_events' that is greater than or equal to the 'Z_SCORE' value for the 'SERVICE_ID' (the SERVICE_ID exists in both the confidence_interval table and the historic_events table). But, I want to only look back two years first, and then if the requirement is not met, look back three years, then four years and then five years (and then stop).

Comment: Please post some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Ok, i had never heard of sqlfiddle - will check it out and see what I can do.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - it too me some time to figure out how to work sqlfiddle. Here is the link to my sample schema. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70a5b/2

Comment: Ok, messed around with it some more - i'm getting the syntax screwed up somewhere. I want to pull a list of 'EVENT_ID' from 'historic_events' within the last two years of 'END_DATE', and I want the result to be greater than or equal to the value provided by 'confidence_interval.Z_SCORE' (the common field being 'SERVICE_ID' between the two tables). If that criteria is not met, I want the query to then look back 3 years, 4 years and finally 5 years, stopping when it has achieved the goal of 'COUNT(EVENT_ID) >= confidence_interval.Z_SCORE'. [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c8b5/5 @Barmar

Comment: You only want to widen the time interval if there are no events that meet the smaller interval?

Comment: Yes, exactly. @Barmar

Comment: Does this have to be done entirely in SQL? It would be easier if you could do the loop in the caller. Repeat the query with a different age limit until it returns something.

Comment: Coincidentally, I'm working on a similar query for my job, and that's the approach I've decided to take. The loop will be in the PHP script that uses the query results.

Comment: I'm very much a novice at SQL and have built all my tables in a MySQL database. I'm using MySQL workbench to build SQL queries (but I do have note++ installed on my machine). I'm very much open to achieving the desired results how you have suggested, just not sure about the PHP side of the equation at all (I briefly used XAMPP which I think had a PHP module built in).

Comment: I'm still working on the answer for this, but the approach I am going to take is to create 6 stored procedures. The procedures will be simple select queries: 'select * from historic_events where END_DATE <= 01/01/2013'. Then I plan on creating a CASE to test multiple conditions, with a command after each condition to run the corresponding stored procedure. Which ever set of conditions comes up as true first will determine which stored procedure is run. I will come back and answer my own question if I get the result I am looking for.